# Как подключить триггеры к DataTemplate в коде?

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть `ListView`, который заполняется из кода (т.к. число столбцов изначально неизвестно). Заполняется список подобным образом:

```
private void FillListView(DataTable table)
{
    GridView grid = (GridView)lvMain.View;

    // Create data triggers
    var mouseOverTrigger = new DataTrigger();
    mouseOverTrigger.Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("IsMouseOver") };
    mouseOverTrigger.Value = true;
    mouseOverTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BackgroundProperty, Colors.Blue));

    var mouseNotOverTrigger = new DataTrigger();
    mouseNotOverTrigger.Binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("IsMouseOver") };
    mouseNotOverTrigger.Value = false;
    mouseNotOverTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(Border.BackgroundProperty, Colors.White));

    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {

        var gridColumn = new GridViewColumn()
        {
            Header = col.ColumnName,
            DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(col.ColumnName)
        };

        gridColumn.CellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        gridColumn.CellTemplate.Triggers.Add(mouseOverTrigger);
        gridColumn.CellTemplate.Triggers.Add(mouseNotOverTrigger);

        grid.Columns.Add(gridColumn);
    }
    lvMain.ItemsSource = ((IListSource)table).GetList();
}
```

Триггеры не срабатывают. Как можно заставить ячейки отзываться на появление над ней курсора? Триггеры не принципиальны, но ничего проще я пока не нашёл.

Comment: Почему вы не использовали XAML, привязки?

Comment: Почитайте про то, как разрабатывают приложения в WPF, в коде использовать контролы бред, это подход может уместен в WinForms (и то не факт), но не в WPF. WPF имеет 2 очень важных аспекта, который кардинально меняют подход к созданию приложения. 1. Xaml - это довольно мощный инструмент, который позволяет написать нужный дизайн, нужные "реакции", без использование c# кода вовсе. Не использовать его - грех, лучше уж идите и пишите WinForm приложение, там я могу понять такой подход.

Comment: 2. Binding - это некая вещь. которая многое делает за вас, вам достаточно создать свойство и указать его как источник, все, XAML сам создаст нужные объекты, сам применит необходимое и отобразит как положено. И это тоже надо обязательно уметь делать при написание WPF приложения. У вас должно быть по сути `<GridView ItemsSource = "{Binding MyCollection}"><Нужные стили и тригеры /></GridView>`.

Comment: `ListView не привязывается к таблице, откуда может получить столбцы.` - бред говорите, либо ваша "таблица" не является коллекцией, которая подходит для привязки. `Он может отображать столбцы, но они должны быть объявлены` - забудьте про UI, забудьте про столбцы, как вы это написали бы в консольном приложении? Наверно бы сделали класс, который содержал бы в себе свойства необходимые для его работы и отображение, затем сделали бы коллекцию этого класса и динамически ее обновляли, так? Вот попробуйте сделать свою задачу без интерфейса, в консоли и уж затем думайте об UI.

Comment: И зачем тогда мне писать для вас сейчас развернутый ответ (а я хотел), если вы не хотите принимать своих ошибок и понимать как работает WPF, да еще и сейчас пытаетесь наехать на меня? Чтож, удачи тогда!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема не в триггерах, а в свойстве `DisplayMemberBinding`, которое стоит по приоритету выше, чем `DataTemplate`: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.displaymemberbinding?view=netframework-4.8